# Deneb Waffle chart (percentual share) displays correctly in PBI desktop however shows as blank in PBI Service

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

could anyone please help with my issue? I´ve created couple of DENEB visuals which seem to be working fine both in PBI Desktop and service however the one I´m sharing doesn´t work in PBI service, it shows as blank.
Do you know by chance what might be the problem?

Here is the JSON that I´m using:

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "NrOfSfhifts",
          "as": "TotalOrigin"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "NrOfSfhifts",
          "as": "TotalOriginGrouped"
        }
      ],
      "groupby": ["NrOfSfhifts"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "round(datum.TotalOriginGrouped/datum.TotalOrigin * 100)",
      "as": "PercentOfTotal"
    },
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {
          "op": "average",
          "field": "PercentOfTotal",
          "as": "Percento"
        }
      ],
      "groupby": ["Dispatcher"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "sequence(1,datum.Percento+1)",
      "as": "S"
    },
    {"flatten": ["S"]},
    {
      "window": [
        {"op": "row_number", "as": "id"}
      ],
      "sort": [
        {
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "TotalOriginGrouped",
          "order": "ascending"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "ceil (datum.id / 10)",
      "as": "row"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.id - datum.row * 10",
      "as": "col"
    }
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "circle",
    "filled": true,
    "tooltip": true,
    "stroke": "black",
    "strokeWidth": 2
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "col",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": null,
      "sort": "x"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "row",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": null,
      "sort": "y"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Dispatcher",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": [
        {
          "op": "sum",
          "field": "TotalOriginGrouped",
          "order": "descending"
        }
      ],
      "scale": {
        "range": [
          "#FFD300",
          "#ed3419",
          "lightgray",
          "white",
          "black",
          "olive",
          "lightblue"
        ]
      },
      "legend": {
        "orient": "right",
        "offset": 10,
        "labelOffset": 3,
        "titlePadding": 5,
        "titleFontSize": 10
      }
    },
    "size": {"value": 330},
    "tooltip": [
      {
        "field": "Dispatcher",
        "type": "nominal"
      },
      {
        "field": "Percento",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "format": "0",
        "formatType": "pbiFormat"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is my code :).

If this is working in the desktop but not the service, then your admin has probably disabled non-native visuals. You should ask them to enable certified visuals at the very least as there is no danger from those.

Comment: Might be, I recycled it from some article :) good job then :)
Actually I´ve found out the root cause - I changed the column value to a measure and now it works also in PBI Service!